# Get document id from firebase flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I trying to get the new created document id after data has been stored to firebase database, but get error

```
E/flutter (20333): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'listen' was called on null.
E/flutter (20333): Receiver: null
E/flutter (20333): Tried calling: listen(Closure: (String) => void)
```

**send_data_bloc**

```
 _repository
          .addOrder(order)
          .listen((documentId) => print(documentId));
```

**repository**

```
@override
  Observable<String> addOrder(Order order) {
      var a = endpoints.collectionEndpoint.add(order.toJson());
      a.then((val) {
        return Observable.fromFuture(val.documentID());
      });
```

**endpoints**

```
  @override
  get collectionEndpoint => _firestore
      .collection(collectionName)
      .document(this.id)
      .collection(orderCollectionName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should return the future from the repository and await for the future on the bloc. Let me try to give a full code snippet here. It would be something like this:

**send_data_bloc**

```
final documentId = await _repository
      .addOrder(order);
print(documentId);
return documentId;
```

**repository**

```
@override
Future<String> addOrder(Order order) {
  return endpoints.collectionEndpoint.add(order.toJson());
```

**endpoints**

```
@override
get collectionEndpoint => _firestore
  .collection(collectionName)
  .document(this.id)
  .collection(orderCollectionName);
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<DocumentReference>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Observable<String>>'

Comment: Hi John, i really think you should work with firebase types DocumentReference. Still don't know wht you are using an observable of string

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
a.then((val) {
        return Observable.fromFuture(val.documentID());
});
```

you are returning the observable within the then function, i believe this is not the expected behavior.

One thing you should do to improve your code quality and readability is to just user async/await. The function on the repository can be rewrited like that:

```
@override
Observable<String> addOrder(Order order) async {
  var documentID = await endpoints.collectionEndpoint.add(order.toJson());
  return Observable.fromFuture(val.documentID());
```

Try this. This should do the trick.

Comment: If I follow your method, I need to declare `addOrder` function as `Future<Observable<String>> addOrder(Order order) async {`.  I will get error on the `.listen.` , which is `The method 'listen' isn't defined for the class 'Future'`.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the reason why you are using Observables? Is this a firebase thing?

You could adjust to:

```
final var documentId = await _repository.addOrder(order);
print(documentId)
```

Comment: but I want `documentID` return to `send_data_bloc`

Comment: What does `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: "JlssLO5vO2Jqt8q4gocy" mean in this line` ? `return Observable.fromFuture(val.documentID());`

Comment: The Receiver is documentID.

Comment: You got the documentId value printed? You can just return documentId from the send_data_bloc method

Comment: Yes, I got documentId printed. But how to return it from `repository` to `send_data_bloc` ?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem here is a snippet of how i approached it

```
//notice im using add while referencing the document reference

final DocumentReference documentReference=await Firestore.instance.collection('jobs').add({

      'jobid':"",
    });
```

then get your id from documentReference

```
final String jobIdd=documentReference.documentID;
```

after getting the id now you can add your document to cloud firestore

```
Firestore.instance.collection('jobs').document(jobIdd).setData({
       'category': category,          
      'description': description,
      'datePosted': formattedDate,
      'postedby': userid,
      'jobid':jobIdd,
    });
```

[image]